# How to make mercurial notify work for other people's push when they don't trust the repo's owner?

Tags: mercurial

I have a team repo setup in our LAN, and it's group writable so everyone can freely push.

(Note: the repo is purely for experimentation so I don't want any limit/check on push.)

Now I want to use the `notify` extension to send email whenever a push happens. It works fine with my own push, but it does not work for others unless they trust my user, otherwise their `hg push` doesn't read the repo's `hgrc`, thus no notification.

I don't want to force everyone to blindly trust me (because I could then easily use a hook/extension to steal their bank accounts--evil grin). Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(They say that describing a problem to others usually helps solving it yourself. Just happened again.)

The trivial solution is to add the relevant `notify` config items to the other team members's user hgrc.

Comment: That's the Rubber Duck Method!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @Chris Morgan: there's a [2-day block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55552/remove-the-two-day-waiting-period-for-accepting-ones-own-answer) for accepting own answer. Please upvote to shorten it a bit.